# Count days from registration date to today

Tags: date

I'd like to add extra text to users who signed up for more the x days.

My function is as follows:

```
   $today           = current_time( 'mysql' );
   $days_diff       = date( 'd', $today);   
   $register_date   = strtotime( get_the_author_meta( 'user_registered', $post_author_id ) );
   $register_on = date_i18n( get_option('date_format'), $register_date );

   echo sprintf( __( '%s ago', 'kiwi' ), apply_filters( 'string_format_i18n', human_time_diff( $register_date ) ) );
```

When I use a var_dump on `$today`, `$days_diff`, and `$register_date`

```
string(19) "2016-06-13 13:50:38" 
string(2) "01" 
string(12) "June 3, 2016"
```

The problem is `$days_diff`. 
Anyone an idea how to change this variable so that it will counts the days from registration date to `$today`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this [answer from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3923228/800452) as a basis which using functions from PHP 5.2.2

---

The main issue is that [`human_time_diff()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/human_time_diff/) doesn't always return days, nor does it have a parameter on what to return. This function just returns how long they have been registered, whether it's days, weeks, months, or years. I believe the most reliable solution is to do this all in PHP really:

```
$today_obj      = new DateTime( date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'today' ) ) );            // Get today's Date Object
$register_date  = get_the_author_meta( 'user_registered', get_current_user_id() );  // Grab the registration Date
$registered_obj = new DateTime( date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $register_date ) ) );     // Get the registration Date Object
$interval_obj   = $today_obj->diff( $registered_obj );                              // Retrieve the difference Object

if( $interval_obj->days > 1 ) {             // The most commonly hit condition at the top
    echo __( "Registered {$interval_obj->days} days ago", "kiwi" );
} elseif( 0 == $interval_obj->days ) {      // IF they registered today
    echo __( 'Registered Today', 'kiwi' );
} elseif( 1 == $interval_obj->days ) {      // IF they registered yesterday
    echo __( 'Registered Yesterday', 'kiwi' );
} else {                                    // The off-chance we have less than zero
    echo __( 'Registered', 'kiwi' );
}
```

In this answer we are using the [PHP DateTime Class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) to get what we need. I removed the `i18n` functions and filters and I don't believe they're needed since we are just dealing with integers and not a specific date / time.

If the code-comments need more clarification, leave a comment below and I'll expand on it.