# Count time from registration date to today

Tags: date, date-time, count, timestamp

I would like to add to the user profile the time from registration to the current day in the format:

> **With us:** 7 years 3 months 2 weeks 6 days

OR

> **With us:** 1 year 1 month 1 week 1 day

Me a bit helped this post [Count days from registration date to today](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/229607/count-days-from-registration-date-to-today), but there countdown goes only in days.

Answer (score 0):

Just gave an example of how to do it:

```php
$today_date      = new DateTime( date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'today' ) ) );
    $register_date  = get_the_author_meta( 'user_registered', get_current_user_id() );
    $registered = new DateTime( date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $register_date ) ) );
    $interval_date   = $today_date->diff( $registered );
        if( $interval_date->days < 31 ) {
            echo 'With us ' . $interval_date->format('%d days');
            }
        elseif( $interval_date->days < 365 ) {
            echo 'With us ' . $interval_date->format('%m months %d days');
            }
        elseif( $interval_date->days > 365 ) {
            echo 'With us ' . $interval_date->format('%y years %m month %d days');
            }
```